# Можно ли так (см.) сказать, представляя ресторан?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов

> На суд публики представлены достойные размышления на темы
>   средиземноморской кухни.

В контексте:

> В ресторане экседры Диоклетиана скромный интерьер, зато и цены, в
>   отличие от «Aroma», поспокойнее. На суд публики представлены достойные
>   размышления на темы средиземноморской кухни. Даже если с чем-то вы не
>   будете согласны, по меньшей мере это занимательно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Витиевато, но почему бы нет? Блюда — размышления, что тут такого? Только эпитет "достойные" мне не очень нравится.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59037/discussion-on-answer-by-niemand-------).

Answer (score 1):

Очень смелая метафора, от текста отвлекает. А если так:  **На суд публики представлены интересные эксперименты на тему средиземноморской кухни.**

Comment: Это было бы хорошо, но скорее всего, никаких "экспериментов" там и в помине нет. Автор хотел "почудесатее" выразиться. К тому же "эксперимент" в кулинарии (да и не только в ней) может быть только один раз. Потом блюдо или принимается и становится фирменным или исчезает в небытие.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему ваш автор уже основательно уверился в собственных текстах. 
Конечно же, назвать блюда размышлением, достойным - да еще представить их на суд публики может только очень эпатажная личность. Но "публика" не хочет судить о размышлениях, она хочет есть.

Comment: Здесь не говорится о блюдах. Контекста автор вопроса не дал, возможно сам не зная — блюдо, презентация, или мелодекламация.

Comment: @shampar  А о чем тогда, если не о блюдах?!

Comment: Есть практика, теория, история. Есть перспективы. Всё это можно красиво выразить в словах. «Занимательно.» Вряд ли экспериментальное-невкусное может показаться занимательным.

Comment: Ребяты! Это "прогулка" по римским ресторанам, за ручку. Так как представлены многие едальные заведения, у читателя (готовящегося пожить в Риме) не возникнет недоумений типо блюдо или презентация. Но мы автора очень расстроим...

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova *у читателя* - понятно. Ему что пища духовная, что физическая - без разницы.  Автору, видать, тоже. Типа, угадал с целевой аудиторией.

Answer (score -2):

Бездарный и пошлый эстетизм. Русский язык в этих фразах формально не порушен и не оскорблен, но понты, витиеватость... очень поганый текст от и для тех, кто хочет ощущать себя "не как все".
Итог - сказать можно, но текст не нейтральный , а с четким позиционированием *себя и ЦА* ("Максим", "GQ" и прочий аналогичный глянец).

Comment: Постарайтесь в своих ответах поменьше выражать эмоций, ответам они только мешают.

Comment: Ярлыки и приговоры — не ответ. Автор вопроса и так понимает какой материал держит в руках и кто заказывает музыку. Ему нужен совет.

Comment: @shampar - я с совета как раз ответ и начал (первое предложение), и постарался быть короток. Политкорректной толерасне тон не понравился? А за это уже модно минусить?

Comment: Совет, как и  Марк Из♦, я не вижу. Если заглянуть в историю этой серии вопросов от Galina Avanesova, будут понятны её проблемы.